# How to disable UIButton and disable touchEvent responder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uibutton

I have `IBOutlet UIButton`. It doesn't respond to `touchesBegan:withEvent:` when it's enabled. But when I set `[button setEnabled:NO]` and click to rect where it is, it goes to `touchesBegan:withEvent:`.

How to disable `UIButton`, and disable `touchEvent responder`?
I had tried `[button setEnabled:NO]` and `[button setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]`, but nothing .

Comment: userInteractionEnabled:YES ??? :O

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ?

```
[button setEnabled:NO];
```

and

```
[button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]
```

Answer (score 0):

for disable touchesBegan:withEvent you may use

```
 self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

because this method used for uiview (and other class which subclassing of uiimage). When you click in button, invoke button handler (not touchesBegan, touchMove), button is subclass of UIControl.

Comment: I can't disable userInteraction for main view.

Comment: in which class you use this button? app delegate, custom uiview or custom uiviewcontroller? Try self.superview.userInteractionEnabled = NO; (for custom uiview - this will be main view). For app delegate you can try this: self.window.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: custom uiviewcontroller, and button with image

Answer (score 0):

if button disabled. a following code is good for you.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, [touch locationInView:self.view]))
        return;

   //do stuff
}
```